# Autocallable Typescript file

Tags: javascript, typescript

Anyone knows how to make a class or function on Typescript that executes its self on document ready?

I have a view, loaded with ajax, and I want to init some components on document ready without using javascript directly.

The Typescript is beeing transpiled to javascript with AMD. 
So, if I use imports or exports, all the code is surrounded by a function call.

For example:

Typescript:

```
import Module from 'module';

class initTest {

  public constructor() {
    //init something here
  }
}

let test = new initTest();
```

Javascript generated:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
  "use strict";
  Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
  var initTest = /** @class */ (function () {
    function initTest() {
        //init something here
    }
    return initTest;
  }());
  var test = new initTest();
});
//# sourceMappingURL=test.js.map
```

Comment: "...without using javascript directly" So what do you intend to use? The only way you can call a function or instantiate an instance of a class is to call the function or the constructor, respectively.

Comment: I mean, if it is possible to call itself in the .ts file

Comment: Sure, there's nothing stopping you. Have you tried adding the code for calling the function at the end of the `.ts` file?

Comment: Yes, but the js generated has everything inside the module

Comment: I made it. If I don't export the class, the module does not include my init code! Thanks

Comment: I'm not following. Exporting does not effect surrounding code. Importing that code might.  Please post some example code that exhibits the problem.

Comment: I edited my question with more details.

Comment: Right, that looks fine to me. You still need to import the module somewhere to make it execute.

Comment: I wanted to avoid that, but thanks :(

Comment: No can do. If you store code in a module, it has to be imported for code in that module to run. Why don't you want to import code you want to run?

Comment: Because I didn't want to add a js file just to init other modules

Comment: I'm not sure what build system you're using but you can usually specify an entry point. That means you could specify that file as your entry point and it will start running as soon as you load it.

Comment: I'm using Asp.net MVC